# How to adjust line height in TextView with multiple type sizes?

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView that holds a Spannable string.  The string contains a bunch of text, the first word of which is double the typesize as the rest of the string.

The problem is that the line spacing between the first and second line is much larger than the line spacing between subsequent lines due to the increased size of the first word.

http://img.skitch.com/20100615-fwd2aehbsgaby8s2s9psx3wwii.png

The spannable string was created using the following code snippet:

```
    // Price
    CharSequence text = "$30 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    final Pattern priceRegex = Pattern.compile("^(.[0-9]+)\\s.*");
    final Matcher m = priceRegex.matcher(text!=null ? text : "");
    if( m.matches() ) {
        text = new SpannableString(text);
        ((SpannableString)text).setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2), 0, m.end(1), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

How can I fix my TextView so that all lines have the same spacing?

Answer (score 43):

You can try using one of these TextView properties:

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier
android:lineSpacingExtra
```

to at least try to make all lines the same height (same as the first one).

Comment: wouldn't it also multiple the line spacing of the first line proportionally?

Comment: Note that `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` is only available in API level 16 and later.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and this solution did not work. Like @emmby said it does scale the spacings of **all** lines proportionally.

Comment: @yiati : Method `setLineSpacing()` and `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` is available from API level 1. Method `getLineSpacing()` is available from API level 16.
You can refer this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingMultiplier

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial and error I got a very hacky solution to work:

1. I added spannables with the same doubled text size as the emphasized word to every space inside the text. This way the whole TextView got the same (big) line spacing. Be aware that you can not reuse a spannable.
2. Then I gave the TextView a negative lineSpacingExtra so the line spacing looked nice again.
3. To avoid unnatuarally wide spaces due to the increased text size I added a ScaleXSpan to every space, scaling them to 50% of their original big size.

This method should work even for TextViews that hold localized strings (where you never know at which position the emphasized word appears or how long your line will be) as long as every line holds at least one space character.

Comment: I like the way you think!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function:

**INPUT**

- LinearLayout ll :

  > the Layout which will be your "TexView" (make sure its orientation is vertical)
- String money:

  > the String you want to be different (in your case bigger textsize)
- String text:

  > the text
- Context mContext

  > the context

**WHAT TO DO**

> I commented the parts that you must edit

---

```
private void populateText(LinearLayout ll,
        String money, String text , Context mContext) { 
    String [] textArray = text.split(" ");
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    ll.removeAllViews();
    int maxWidth = display.getWidth() - 20;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params; // to be used over and over
    LinearLayout newLL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    newLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    int widthSoFar = 0;

    ///FIRST INSERT THE MONEY TEXTVIEW
    LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM); //THIS IS IMPORTANT TO keep spacing up not down
    LL.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView TV = new TextView(mContext);
    TV.setText(money);
    //TV.setTextSize(size);  <<<< SET TEXT SIZE
    TV.measure(0, 0);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TV.getMeasuredWidth(),
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);  // YOU CAN USE THIS
    LL.addView(TV, params);
    LL.measure(0, 0);
    widthSoFar += TV.getMeasuredWidth();// YOU MAY NEED TO ADD THE MARGINS
    newLL.addView(LL, params);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < textArray.length ; i++ ){
        LL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM);
        LL.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TV = new TextView(mContext);
        TV.setText(textArray[i]);
        //TV.setTextSize(size);  <<<< SET TEXT SIZE
        TV.measure(0, 0);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TV.getMeasuredWidth(),
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);  // YOU CAN USE THIS
        LL.addView(TV, params);
        LL.measure(0, 0);
        widthSoFar += TV.getMeasuredWidth();// YOU MAY NEED TO ADD THE MARGINS
        if (widthSoFar >= maxWidth) {
            ll.addView(newLL);

            newLL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            newLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LL
                    .getMeasuredWidth(), LL.getMeasuredHeight());
            newLL.addView(LL, params);
            widthSoFar = LL.getMeasuredWidth();
        } else {
            newLL.addView(LL);
        }
    }
    ll.addView(newLL);
}
```

---

**NOTE**

> I have not tested it ... I used it for more complex things and it was working ... You might need to tweak a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't :(.
Android os calculate the gaps between the lines according the font size, so that '30$' makes gap between line 1 and line 2 to be bigger, and I do not know if it is possible to control this gap size.

To solve this you can easily extend LinearLayuot and put the orientation vertical. Than put 2 textviews with fillparent for width....

and than implement function , let say setNoGapText(String s);
, and in this function you can measure the text that can be fit in the textview on the top(this can me done with textutils), and than the rest of the text will be fit on textview2...

between this textview you can play with padding and margins properties so the gaps between lines will look just like you imagine them.