# Highlight-style effect with multiline text in Android

Tags: android, textview

What I would like to achieve is an effect that looks like this with a TextView:

[image]

Basically having a background, but keeping the space between the lines. The only solution I came up with was using one `TextView` for each line of text, but I would prefer a cleaner one using only one multiline `TextView`.

Any ideas?

Comment: please check the  following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8661622/957654

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextView with background color and line spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939862/textview-with-background-color-and-line-spacing)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use mark tag in html to textview.

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<mark>heading highlighted</mark>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use spanned text for each line. Read the Spannable API.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8661622/957654) as it describes how to implement spacing between multiple lines in  a TextView , using the following properties :

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier 

android:lineSpacingExtra
```

Hope that Helps .
Regards

Comment: The line spacing doesn't work unfortunately, because the background is applied to the whole TextView anyway